# LDAP unsupported critical extension

Tags: ldap

We are using Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition on our LDAP server and the following command gives unsupported critical extension error:

```
SRCH base="OU=dsgroups,DC=adm" scope=2 filter="(&(objectClass=person)(|(cn=jkapsiar*)(uid=jkapsiar*)(givenName=jkapsiar*)(sn=jkapsiar*)(mail=jkapsiar*)(tADupn=jkapsiar*)))", unsupported critical extension
```

I could not find full documentation to see what options it actually supports.

What could be a possible cause of the problem?

Comment: If I'm not wring, I think this is not a command but a line of a log file. Could you provide us with more informations? For example, the command you executed to generate this error, the LDAP server configuration, DIT, etc.

Comment: Unsupported Critical Extension error indicates that the request included an LDAP Control marked as critical that is not supported by DSEE.